Why does CVXPY determine $maximize -\frac{x^2}{y}$ as an objective function thas does not follow DCP rules?
I am solving a convex problem using CVXPY. The following is my written code.
import cvxpy as cp

# Define variables
x = cp.Variable(nonneg = True)
y = cp.Variable(nonneg = True)

# Define the objective and constraint
obj = -1*cp.multiply(cp.power(x,2),cp.inv_pos(y))
objective = cp.Maximize(obj)
constraint = [y <= 1,
              x <= 1]  # Example constraint on y

# Formulate the problem
problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraint)

# Solve the problem
problem.solve()

Is not $-x^2/y$ concave? How can I solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.
I expected cvxpy solve it. but the following error is raised.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DCPError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-ce998626c87f> in <cell line: 17>()
     15 
     16 # Solve the problem
---> 17 problem.solve()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cvxpy/reductions/solvers/solving_chain.py in _reductions_for_problem_class(problem, candidates, gp, solver_opts)
    113             append += ("\nHowever, the problem does follow DQCP rules. "
    114                        "Consider calling solve() with `qcp=True`.")
--> 115         raise DCPError(
    116             "Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:\n" + append)
    117     elif gp and not problem.is_dgp():

DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
power(var243205, 2.0) @ power(var243206 + 0.1, -1.0)


You have to use quad_over_lin to indicate the DCP structure explicitly.

@MichalAdamaszek Thank you. How if both X and Y are vectors to Matrix? How can I do it elementwise? Should I write loops?
